# What is the pin assignment for an OV7670 cam with the ESP32-WROVER-KIT?

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

I have a sketch that takes a picture and sends that picture to a REST interface.
This sketch works great on my ESP32-WROVER-DEV board from Freenove.
[ESP32-WROVER-DEV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxvVY.jpg)

Now I got the ESP-WROVER-KIT from Espressif and would like to upload the sketch to this board. The board comes without a camera, so I got the OV7670. Now I need to change the pinout but I don't know how. [ESP32-WROVER-KIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5T00.jpg)

The first problem is that the OV7670 does not support JPEG. So I changed the PIXFORMAT to RGB565. Can I either easily convert this format to JPEG in my sketch or still send the image to my interface in RGB565 and then convert it to my JavaScript code?

Without changing the pinout, I get the error code:
[camera.c:1483] esp_camera_fb_get(): Failed to get the frame on time!

Not surprising as far as it goes.
However, this error also occurs when I use the pin assignment from the official esp32-camera example from espressif. It doesn't matter which pin assignment I look up on the Internet and use, I get this or other errors.

Does anyone know what the pin assignment should be in my case?

```
Rui Santos
  Complete project details at https://RandomNerdTutorials.com/esp32-cam-post-image-photo-server/
  
  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  of this software and associated documentation files.
  
  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
  copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*/

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "soc/soc.h"
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"

const char* ssid = "********";
const char* password = "*********";

String serverName = "*********.herokuapp.com";  

String serverPath = "/"; 

const int serverPort = 80;

WiFiClient client;
#define CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_NO_PSRAM
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM   -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM    21
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM    26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM    27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM      35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM      34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM      39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM      36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM      19
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM      18
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM      5
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM      4
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM   25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM    23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM    22
const int timerInterval = 30000;    // time between each HTTP POST image
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;   // last time image was sent

void setup() {
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0); 
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("ESP32-CAM IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
 config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_RGB565;
  // init with high specs to pre-allocate larger buffers
  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 20;  //0-63 lower number means higher quality
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_CIF;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;  //0-63 lower number means higher quality
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }
  
  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }

  sendPhoto(); 
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= timerInterval) {
    sendPhoto();
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
  }
}

String sendPhoto() {
  String getAll;
  String getBody;

  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if(!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }
  
  Serial.println("Connecting to server: " + serverName);

  if (client.connect(serverName.c_str(), serverPort)) {
      Serial.println("Connection successful!");    
    String head = "--RandomNerdTutorials\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Image\"; filename=\"esp32-cam.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n";
    String tail = "\r\n--RandomNerdTutorials--\r\n";

    uint32_t imageLen = fb->len;
    uint32_t extraLen = head.length() + tail.length();
    uint32_t totalLen = imageLen + extraLen;
  
    client.println("POST " + serverPath + " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + serverName);
    client.println("Content-Length: " + String(totalLen));
    client.println("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=RandomNerdTutorials");
    client.println();
    client.print(head);
  
    uint8_t *fbBuf = fb->buf;
    size_t fbLen = fb->len;
    for (size_t n=0; n<fbLen; n=n+1024) {
      if (n+1024 < fbLen) {
        client.write(fbBuf, 1024);
        fbBuf += 1024;
      }
      else if (fbLen%1024>0) {
        size_t remainder = fbLen%1024;
        client.write(fbBuf, remainder);
      }
    }   
    client.print(tail);
    
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
    
    int timoutTimer = 10000;
    long startTimer = millis();
    boolean state = false;
    
    while ((startTimer + timoutTimer) > millis()) {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(100);      
      while (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        if (c == '\n') {
          if (getAll.length()==0) { state=true; }
          getAll = "";
        }
        else if (c != '\r') { getAll += String(c); }
        if (state==true) { getBody += String(c); }
        startTimer = millis();
      }
      if (getBody.length()>0) { break; }
    }
    Serial.println();
    client.stop();
    Serial.println(getBody);
  }
  else {
    getBody = "Connection to " + serverName +  " failed.";
    Serial.println(getBody);
  }
  return getBody;
}
```

I would still use the ESP32-WROVER-DEV board, but it has fewer pins, most of which are occupied by the camera. Then I probably won't be able to connect the RC522 and SSD1306. At least I don't know how that would work. If anyone here has any tips, I'd be happy to take them.

Please explain as simply as possible, I am a complete beginner.